# Error when deploying 2nd gen Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

This [Firebase blog post](https://firebase.blog/posts/2023/07/cloud-functions-firebase-ga-and-python) says that Gen 2 functions are available from 7/31/23, but when I try to `firebase deploy` one of them, I get this error:

> Error: [callGroupRTDBSetup(us-central1)] Upgrading from GCFv1 to GCFv2 is not yet supported. Please delete your old function or wait for this feature to be ready.

A few days ago I recreated my project from scratch, doing `firebase init` all over again. I think the only thing I might not have updated is Node.js. Today I ran `npm update -g firebase-tools` because it told me there was an update available. I also restarted my computer. My `firebase --version` is now 12.4.7.

```
import {onCall} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

exports.callGroupRTDBSetup = onCall({cors: true}, async (req) => {
  try {
    const groupID = req.data.groupID;
    const adminUID = req.data.adminUID;
    const adminUsername = req.data.adminUsername;
    const createdTimestamp = req.data.createdTimestamp;

    await setGroupAdminRTDB(groupID, adminUID, adminUsername, createdTimestamp);

    await addMemberRTDB(groupID, adminUID, adminUsername, createdTimestamp);

    return {
      returnVal: 1,
      returnMsg: "callGroupRTDBSetup success!",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new HttpsError("invalid-argument", "Error: " + error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade?hl=en&authuser=0#migrate_traffic_to_the_new_2nd_gen_functions):

> It is not possible to upgrade a function from 1st to 2nd gen **with the
> same name** and run firebase deploy. Doing so will result in the error:
>
> *Upgrading from GCFv1 to GCFv2 is not yet supported. Please delete your
> old function or wait for this feature to be ready.*

Comment: There is a problem with your link I can't open it. So the solution is to delete the function from the script, run `firebase deploy`, then paste in function again and run `firebase deploy` again?

Comment: Link updated. You can either delete the CF from the Google Cloud console ("Cloud Functions" section) or do as you describe in your comment.

Comment: Hey @whatwhatwhat, did you succeed in deploying the V2 version?

Comment: Deleting the function from the script didn't work. I had to delete from the console and then re-run `firebase deploy`. Side note - when I first tried to deploy the Gen 2 function, my system said that there is some first time setup needed before I can deploy Gen 2 functions and that I should wait a few minutes before deploying again. Hopefully this won't be needed in the future because if I had been trying to deploy a new Gen 2 function to a live production environment, that would have made me very worried lol. Thanks Renaud!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function you don't mind deleting, just [delete it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#delete_functions) and redeploy.

```
firebase functions:delete myFunction

firebase deploy --only functions:myFunction
```

[Here is the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade?hl=en&authuser=0#migrate_traffic_to_the_new_2nd_gen_functions) for this error message.